# linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) on Xcode 8

Tags: xcode, swift3, xcode8, twitter-fabric, mopub

For some reason my Xcode project can't seem to find this :

```
ld: can't map file, errno=22 file, errno=22 file '/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project-cryxdhacrcpvujgnfbdgzfoxctjx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/project/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos' for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Does anyone know a solution to this?

Comment: Did you clean your project and build again? And go to DerivedData directory and delete data in it.

Comment: Yes, tried that SOOOO many times.